# Can someone please find the reason why there is insertion of empty rows in the database except the id field which i have set to auto-increment?

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I am trying to insert data into a database using PHP and Angular js. But whenever I insert, only blank rows get inserted into the database except the id field which has been set to auto-increment.

I have tried to solve this, even I searched about this problem but I could not find much helpful resource.
These are my codes: connection.php and insert.html
Kindly help me find the problem please.

**connection.php**

```
<?php
    $hostname="localhost";
    $dbname="sampledb";
    $username="root";
    $password="";

    $conn=mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $info=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $empname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info['empname']);
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info['email']);
    $salary=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info['salary']);
    $query="insert into empdetails(empname, email, salary) values 
    ('$empname','$email','$salary')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
    {
        echo"Result inserted successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo"Oops! Failed to insert.";
    }
?>
```

**insert.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/
    angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        var app=angular.module("Myapp",[]);
        app.controller("Mycontroller",function($scope,$http)
        {
            $scope.insert=function()
            {
                $http.post('connection.php',
                {
                    'empname'=$scope.empname;
                    'email'=$scope.email;
                    'salary'=$scope.salary;
                })
                .success(function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    $scope.empname=null;
                    $scope.email=null;
                    $scope.salary=null;
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h1>Insert Records Into Database</h1>
        <hr/>
        <div ng-app="Myapp"ng-controller="Mycontroller">
            Name: <input type="text"ng-model="empname"/><br/>
            Email: <input type="text"ng-model="email"/><br/>
            Salary: <input type="text"ng-model="salary"/><br/>
        <hr/>
        <input type="submit" value="Insert Records"ng-click="Insert()"/>
        </div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First off don't escape your strings like that, use prepared statements. Even escaped strings can be sql injected... Second you need a space here: insert into empdetailsSPACEGOESHERE(e Third please use mysqli as a object oriented language and not procedural

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
Put a true as the second parameter of json_decode

```
$info=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

Alot of things are wrong here, i'll break my comment into answers. The biggest being this:

```
$info=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$empname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info['empname']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info['email']);
$salary=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info['salary']);
```

Json decode returns an object not an array unless you pass it true like so:

```
$info=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

Next lets talk about coding habbits.

First mysqli_real_escape_string is a big no no, use prepared statements as escaping strings can be exploited still.

Next with your query you need to use a space here:

```
$query="insert into empdetails SPACEGOESHERE (empname, email, salary) values 
    ('$empname','$email','$salary')";
```

Finally i'd suggest using mysqli as object oriented instead of procedural, it will look alot better and its better practice.

Comment: I never put a space between table name and column list and it hasn't caused any issues for me in any MySQL version so far. Do you have something to support your statement e.g. Link to Docs?

Comment: Can you please show me a line of my code using prepared statement so that i can understand a bit better. @Lulceltech